# Modifying bulk user account attributes in AD

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

We created around 1,000 users but the first name, last name, display name, and logon name are all in uppercase. Now we are having a hard time changing all of these manually. Is there a way to we can modify all account properties to make name and display name capitalize only the first letter while also making logon name all lowercase?

Comment: Yup, pull each object in powershell and then for each relevant attribute, output it to a string variable, convert it to upper / lower as required, then feed the new strings back in.  What problems are you having in your script to do this?

Comment: It was done by someone manually.

Comment: OK, you'll need to find what we call a 'system administrator' and get them to help you.

Comment: No i wl do myself

Comment: ServerFault is not a script writing service.  However, if you can make a good faith attempt on your own, do a little research, and run into a problem we'll be happy to assist you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic conversion example for just the GivenName (First Name) attribute.  You can use this to help you do the rest.

```
$firstname = (get-aduser -identity ACCOUNTNAME).givenname
$newfirstname = $firstname.Substring(0,1)+$firstname.Substring(1).toLower()
set-aduser ACCOUNTNAME -givenname $newfirstname
```

Comment: Lets try this, powershell?

Comment: Yes, it's powershell.

Comment: What about logon name? actually its all caps, first, name last name, display name, logon name

Comment: Givenname, surname, displayname, samaccountname

Comment: may be after modifying the display name it will help

Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com' -Filter * -Properties firstname | % {Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -firstname $_.name}

Comment: that doesn't works

Comment: `-firstname` is not a valid parameter for `Set-ADUser`.  It's `-givenname`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [sudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) you could use. Sudocode means a basic idea of the logic in English, you'll need to do some research and lookup commands but this should help you get started

```
# Get List of employees and their attributes using Get-ADUser
# Loop over that list of employees using ForEach-Object
## Pull out information about the attributes you need
## Change the case of the values
## Edit the attributes using Set-ADUser (Hint use "$_ | " to make this easier)
# EndLoop
```

If you post an attempt at writing code based on this sudocode I'm sure someone would be able to help you fill in the gaps.